# Plancherel Theorem Discrete Spectrum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am trying to translate Plancherel's Theorem to a specific case of a trigonometric system with discrete spectrum, but am unsure of a few steps in the process. Here is the setup:

We have a trigonometric system over a countably infinite set of elements that converges to real valued functions over the entire real line.

$$f(x)=\sum_{\beta}\hat f(\beta) e^{i\beta x} $$
$$\hat f(\beta)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{i\beta x}dx $$

Now if we start with the spectral side of Plancherel:
$$\sum_{\beta}|\hat f(\beta)|^2 $$
$$=\sum_{\beta}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{i\beta x}dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}\bar{f(y)}e^{-i\beta y}dy$$
$$=\sum_{\beta}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{i\beta x}\bar{f(y)}e^{-i\beta y}dxdy$$
$$=\sum_{\beta}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\bar{f(y)}e^{i\beta (x-y)}dxdy$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\bar{f(y)}\delta(x-y)dxdy$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\bar{f(y)}dx$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^2dx$$

Question: Are the above steps correct (swapping sum and integrals) for a sum over a discrete spectrum, what is the justification? Most of the proofs of Plancherel that i have seen involve a continuous spectrum, where the delta function is justified, or DFT where both sides are discrete... i'm unsure if we can make that leap in this case.

Comment: Probably a dropped minus sign... also, more seriously, what hypotheses do you have on the collection of $\beta$'s? And, mostly, the integral of such $f$ over $\mathbb R$ is simply not going to converge ... ?!? Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for the questions (ill edit question if this response makes sense): the $\beta$s are real. for simplicity, lets say $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$. Lets also say $f(x)\in L^2$ <-is this the convergence you mean (for $\int |f(x)|^2$), or are you referring to convergence of the complex exponentials to $f(x)$? the actual case i have has convergence of the complex exponentials to f(x) as a distribution, but i was curious about the general case.

Comment: For some reason i can't edit the above comment. i just realized that $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$ doesn't really generalize b/c i have just seen a proof that works in the specific case where the $\beta$'s are integers... lets say $\beta$ is just some countably infinite set of real numbers

Comment: If the $\beta$'s are just a countable set of real numbers (probably going to infinity?), then I don't know what the $L^2$ norm should be. Probably can't be an integral over the whole line, but (with incommensurable $\beta$'s) can't be a finite interval, because the $f$'s aren't periodic. Perhaps google Harold Bohr's "almost periodic functions", to see whether that's heading in the direction you want. Plancherel for distributions only works well on suitable Sobolev spaces...